# How to "map" an image

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a good way to "map" an image in android, I mean I have an image, figure a photo, and if an user taps on a body launch an activity, if he taps on a phone start something else and so on.
I'm sorry if the question is stupid but it's way complicated google something you dont fully understand xD

EDIT:
googling something seems an imageMap function does not exists, so how can I manage different taps on a single image ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about replicating the functionality of an HTML image map? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

Comment: yea that was I was thinking, of course I would like to use an android method if there is any, or a different approach if my idea is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've founded something looking around and speaking with some friends at the university, basically a common way is to duplicate the image and color each section of a different flat colour, then in a layout you have to overlay those two images and set the visibility attribute of the second image ( the once with flat colour ) to false, in this way users will see the normal image, but we can call the methos getColour() on a tap event and desume where the user tapped.